# the multi-part identifier could not be bound after multi inclusion of one table in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm loading twice the same table in two joins in the sale select:

```
  INNER JOIN [dbo].pstl_Unit ON [dbo].pstl_Unit.UnitId = pstl_UnitPosition.FK_Unit
  INNER JOIN [dbo].pstl_Unit ON [dbo].pstl_Unit.UnitId = VW_PERS_Visibilite.FK_Unit
```

to make it work, I have to use the AS keyword:

```
  INNER JOIN [dbo].pstl_Unit AS pos ON [dbo].pstl_Unit.UnitId = pstl_UnitPosition.FK_Unit
  INNER JOIN [dbo].pstl_Unit AS vis ON [dbo].pstl_Unit.UnitId = VW_PERS_Visibilite.FK_Unit
```

but here I'm facing to one issue:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "dbo.pstl_Unit.UnitId" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The multi-part identifier "dbo.pstl_Unit.UnitId" could not be bound.
```

I want to be able to see two units in the select.

Thanks in advance to help me

Comment: You have to use the aliases in the `ON` clauses, like: `ON pos.UnitId = pstl_UnitPosition.FK_Unit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using alias names, you should specify the alias name in join.

Replace `[dbo].pstl_Unit` with the corresponding alias name:

```
INNER JOIN [dbo].pstl_Unit AS pos ON pos.UnitId = pstl_UnitPosition.FK_Unit
INNER JOIN [dbo].pstl_Unit AS vis ON vis.UnitId = VW_PERS_Visibilite.FK_Unit
```